# Heroku Postgresql local connection

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

Everything worked great until today, while I did not change anything in the code.
I can't connect to the database not from the application, not from the IDE, did something go wrong on the heroku side? I have not seen news with global updates over the past couple of days on the heroku website. Can anyone advise how to solve the current problem?
I use the free version of dyno and postgresql, I definitely still have a lot of free space (less than 1 thousand fields). It looks like blocking access to the database locally, not from the service side.

Comment: Are you getting your connection information from the app's `DATABASE_URL` environment variable? That information can change at any time.

Comment: @Chris I checked It, It still the same. Seems to me that Heroku or Amazon blocked access from remote IDE like dbeaver. Don't you meet the same issue? Everything work from dyno but not from my local computer anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would try in your situation:

- Go to https://data.heroku.com/, select your Datastore and check everything there: Health, number of connections, number of rows, data size.
- If everything is fine: Go to settings -> database credentials and try setting up a connection from any desktop tool such as Navicat or Pgadmin. What error message do you get?
- Set-up another database on Heroku and try the same. If the second DB works, there is an issue with the first one. If it does not, it's rather about your setup/settings.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for share the link! It works now, I didn't change anything. Perhaps it was downtime? For hobby tier it is "< 4 hr downtime per mo." but for me it was more, around 8  hours of downtime. Strange... At least now we know that it was not blocked from outside by Heroku or Amazon